# How to run R version > 3 on EC2 or update Debian

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

I am trying to run R on AWS. I followed these instructions: http://randyzwitch.com/r-amazon-ec2/?utm_content=buffer6b6e9&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer and http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/r-in-the-cloud-part-1.html

Although I'm successfully running R on the cloud, I found that it is an old version of R (2.11.1). As a result, it does not support many packages such as "RODBC" and "plyr." I think it is due to Amazon Elastic MapReduce running Debian/Squeeze, not the latest version of Debian. Is it possible to update Debian? How can I run a newer version of R on EC2 (ideally 3.1.0)?

I have not figured out how to update Debian within the current AMI. But I decided to close the instance and kick up a new instance running Debian 7.5. I will update if it allows me to run R 3.1.

---

UPDATE:

I'm closing this question since I found a way to work around the problem. The details are in the answer.

Comment: Have you done any searching on your own?

Comment: Of course I have. The question you marked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924780/unable-to-install-r-rmr2-on-aws-emr is not the same question at all. I am installing the latest version of R. But due to old version AMI limitations (running Debian 6), R 2.11.1 is the newest version that can be installed successfully. The system did that automatically. I am asking if it is possible to update Debian (to Debian 7.5) within the current AMI.

Comment: In addition, I am trying to get the latest version of R running on EC2, brevitylabs asked how to install the packages running an old version of R.

Comment: does http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ help?

Comment: @BenBolker So you are suggesting installing a new AMI? That is what I'm trying to do. However, I can't use whatever AMI I want, since I'm working in a corporate.

Comment: I followed instructions here to install R:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-on-amazon-linux/ .

Instructions http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360158/cannot-install-rstudio-on-centos-6-4 give great guidance of installing Rstudio.

Also http://toreopsahl.com/2011/10/17/securely-using-r-and-rstudio-on-amazons-ec2/ helps to get access to Rstudio server from your browser, which is really cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by kicking up a new instance running the latest version of Amazon AMI (3.1.0).

It supports R 3.0.2. But since it's running Amazon Linux, not Ubuntu or Debian, the installation of R is a little different.

Also, Ben Bolker's comment includes a link to community AMI's that support latest versions of R and Rstudio.

I followed instructions here to install R: http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-on-amazon-linux/ .

The answer in [Cannot install RStudio on CentOS 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360158/cannot-install-rstudio-on-centos-6-4) gives great trouble-shooting for installing Rstudio.